# Adding dynamic data to StackedAreaChart in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to change the data of the `StackedAreaChart` dynamically. So I have created an `fxml` file and a controller for it.

[image]

fig.fxml

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="495.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gollahalli.test.controller">
   <children>
      <StackedAreaChart fx:id="graph" layoutX="24.0" layoutY="95.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
        <xAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="BOTTOM" />
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis side="LEFT" />
        </yAxis>
      </StackedAreaChart>
      <TextField fx:id="number" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="39.0" />
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="330.0" layoutY="39.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller.java

```
public class controller {

    @FXML
    private Button button;
    @FXML
    private TextField number;
    @FXML
    private StackedAreaChart<Number, Number> graph;

    public void initialize(){


        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();

        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
            System.out.println(number1);

            for (int i = 0; i < number1; i++) {
                series.getData().addAll(new XYChart.Data(i, i));
            }
            graph.getData().add(series);

        });
    }

}
```

When I enter a number say 100, I am able to get the graph correctly, when I change the data say 101 and click on the button I get an error as `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added`.

I do know that to overcome this I would have to use `ObservableList`, but I am not sure how to use it.

Now the question is, how should I change/refresh the data every time I click on the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message is clear. To avoid it add series only once:

```
public void initialize(){
    XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
    // add series only once at init
    graph.getData().add(series);

    button.setOnAction(event -> {
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(number.getText());
        System.out.println(number1);

        // clear current data
        series.getData().clear();

        // add new data
        for (int i = 0; i < number1; i++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, i));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: finally! then why use ObservableList?

Comment: @akshay you are already using it. The `graph.getData()` gives you `ObservableList<XYChart.Series<X,Y>>` and `series.getData()` gives you `ObservableList<XYChart.Data<X,Y>>`. ObservableList is just an observable list (duh!) ;)